# Spring test - @ContextConfiguration can't load resource

Tags: java, spring

I have a situation like this.
I have a junit test class in that i have mentioned `@ContextConfiguration` 
but the class load `@ContextConfiguration` from the main/resource and the other files that is included in it(*DataSource.xml* and *Hibernate.xml*) from test/resources.

Please see below my code

**test class**

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath*:/META-INF/spring/springBeanConfiguration.xml"})
```

**springBeanConfiguration.xml**

```
        <!-- Database Configuration -->
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/database/DataSource.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/database/Hibernate.xml"/>
```

there is file named `springBeanConfiguration.xml` resides both in test/resources and main/resource.

Comment: when i remove the resources from test/resources and keep all the file in main/resources it works. I think since i specified 'classpath*' spring will search for the file in the entire context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Maven project, you can configure the `maven-surefire-plugin` (used in the test phase) to declare src/main/webapp as an additional classpath element during test execution.

Or just specify all of them like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:/META-INF/database/DataSource.xml", "classpath*:/META-INF/database/hibernate.xml"})
```